# Spring Bean not initialized correctly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In a spring boot 2 application with spring security, I try to get local when authentication fail

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        I18nLocaleResolver r = new I18nLocaleResolver();
        r.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return r;
    }
}
```

In my **CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler** who extends **SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler**

I have theses attributes

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messages;

@Autowired
private LocaleResolver localeResolver;
```

but when the onAuthenticationFailure method is called, localeResolver and mesages are null

Comment: Is the **CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler** class actually a managed bean by Spring. This means does it have a bean qualifying annotation, otherwise injection points (@Autowired) will always be `null`

Comment: On the class, I tried with @Component("authenticationFailureHandler") and @Component same thing